# How do I use ListBox.Items.AddRange together with a two dimensional array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, listbox

Here is the array:

```
// 2D array of strings.
string[,] calendar2D_Array = new string[33,13];
```

Then I initialize the array with a lot of strings...

I´m trying to let my listbox use the array:

```
private void frmCalender_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxCalender.Items.AddRange(calendar2D_Array);
}
```

The compiler now states:
**cannot convert from 'string[*,*]' to 'object[]'**

If it had been a single dimensional array, there would be no problem... How should I do to get it to work with a two dimensional array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to flatten your 2D array:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,33*13).Select(i => calendar2D_Array[i/13,i%13]).ToArray()
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(0,33*13).Select(i => calendar2D_Array[i%33,i/33]).ToArray()
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for adding a single dimension array of integers to a Listbox control. AddRange is much faster than using a loop (i.e., Listbox1.items.add(iArray(i))

```
ReDim Preserve iArray(iCount - 1) ' Number of items added to Array
ListBox1.BeginUpdate() 
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(iArray.Cast(Of Object).ToArray)
ListBox1.EndUpdate()
```